# Nodemon on Docker container gets "Permission denied"

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, nodemon

I have a Node.js server inside a Docker container that uses Nodemon. On my Windows 10 machine everything is working perfectly, however when I try to install it with docker-compose on Ubuntu I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 8: /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon: Permission denied
```

I have found out that Nodemon sometimes does this and a solution would be to install it globally using sudo. I have done that and I've also tried running an npm install of Nodemon before copying package.json in the Dockerfile but it didn't work. Also, there doesn't seem to be any docker-entrypoint.sh at that location.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.16-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Comment: Bad practice. you should'nt use nodemon inside a counter. rather apply a restart policy to the container

Answer (score 0):

You are missing executable permissions on the binary.
You could add the following torwards the end of your Dockerfile:

```
chmod +x /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon
```